# unable to clear text field in autcomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to add autocomplete in my site. Here the autocomplete is working correctly but I just want to clear that field (searching field) after searching for an item, but it is not happening.

```
function clearThis(target){
    $("#username").val("");
}

function auto(response){
    $("#username").autocomplete({
        source: response,
        select: function(event, ui){
            log( ui.item ? "" + ui.item.label : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            $("#selected_users").html(ui.item.label);
            if (usernames.length) {
                if (usernames.indexOf(ui.item.label)) {
                    usernames.push(ui.item.label);
                }
            }    
            else {
                usernames.push(ui.item.label);
            }
            console.log(usernames);
            clearThis();
        }
    });
}

function log(message) {
    $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
    $("#log").scrollTop(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="" style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial">
    Result:
    <div id="log" style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class=""></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Add Usernames</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div id="selected_users" class="form-group">
    <label>Usernames</label><br>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the logic in your `if` condition on the `usernames.indexOf(ui.item.label)` is flawed. It can return `0` - which means the first item matched, yet your logic would return false. You should check for `-1` being returned to inidicate the string wasn't found. Also, both branches of the condition perform the same logic (pushing to the `usernames` array), so the whole statement is redundant.

Comment: okk... but autocomplete operation is working correctly .... only here is problem is occuring for clearing the text field after searching a field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `return false;` right under your call to `clearThis()` in the select section of autocomplete.